# Understanding how to use APNIC resources or how to get all subnet per country

Tags: ip

I'm trying to get an up-to-date list of IPv4 ranges assigned to a country.

I use `http://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest` to get the list then filter by country extension.

Let's take China.

`curl 'http://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest' | grep ipv4 | grep CN | awk -F\| '{ printf("%s/%d\n", $4, 32-log($5)/log(2)) }' > chnroute.txt`

gives us the list of IPv4 for China if I'm not mistaken.
So far so good.

But some IP ranges seems to be missing from this list.

Let's focus on the `106.0.0.0/8` range for the sake of this example.

We can know the whole range is allocated to Asia Pacific from this page `https://www.apnic.net/publications/research-and-insights/apnic-resource-range`

Excerpt:

`APNIC allocates resources in the following ranges within the Asia Pacific region:
...
106.0.0.0/8
...`

Looking at the list online (`http://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest`), we can see:

`apnic|TW|ipv4|106.1.0.0|65536|20110323|allocated
apnic|CN|ipv4|106.2.0.0|131072|20110321|allocated
apnic|CN|ipv4|106.4.0.0|262144|20110321|allocated`

OK, but what about `106.3.0.0` ?

APNIC Whois can give us the answer: `https://wq.apnic.net/whois-search/static/search.html?query=106.3.0.0/24`

Excerpt:

`inetnum:    106.3.0.0 - 106.3.127.255
netname:    CNISP-UNION
descr:  CNISP-Union Technology (Beijing) Co., Ltd`

Oups, this seems to belong to China as well.

So why isn't it listed in `http://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest` ???
Looking at `ftp://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/` one can find some other resources, but there doesn't seem to be anything more complete.

How can I make sense of this? Do I have to understand `ASN` information listed in this file to get a complete list?

Comment: 106.3.0.0 _is_ listed there!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is founded on an incorrect premiss (sic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RIR statistics exchange format](https://www.apnic.net/publications/media-library/documents/resource-guidelines/rir-statistics-exchange-format)

```
4.3 Record format

...
Format:
registry|cc|type|start|value|date|status[|extensions...]
...
start    In the case of records of type 'ipv4' or 'ipv6' this is the IPv4 or
         IPv6 'first address' of the range.
...
value    In the case of IPv4 address the count of hosts for this range. 
         This count does not have to represent a CIDR range.
```

As you can see, the count of hosts in this allocation  `apnic|CN|ipv4|106.2.0.0|131072|20110321|allocated` is 131072, which is (2^16)***2**, and since `106.2.0.0` is the first address of the range, this allocation includes both `106.2.0.0/16` and `106.3.0.0/16`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was looking for the format description.
But in this case the following subnet 106.4.0.0 could also be included with 
``apnic|CN|ipv4|106.2.0.0|393216|20110321|allocated`` (2^16)*6
What determine the split? The fact that ranges have been allocated to different company I would guess?